# Solr - count documents in the range of two date fields

Tags: date, solr, facet

Here are some example Solr documents I got:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "openDate": "2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "closeDate": "2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "openDate": "2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "closeDate": "2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z"
},
{
  "id": "3",
  "openDate": "2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
  "closeDate": "2017-12-06T00:00:00.000Z" 
}
```

The dates that a document is "active" are the dates between the openDate (inclusive) and the closeDate (exclusive). I want to count the number of documents that are "active" on each day, so the output should be:

```
[
  {
    Date: 2017-12-01,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    Date: 2017-12-02,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    Date: 2017-12-03,
    count: 3
  },
  {
    Date: 2017-12-04,
    count: 1
  },
  {
    Date: 2017-12-05,
    count: 1
  }
]
```

One easy approach to solve this is to keep a multi-valued date field (say called `openDates`) with all the dates in the range of interest, so we expand the documents like this:

```
  {
    "id": "1",
    "openDate": "2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "closeDate": "2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "openDates": ["2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "2017-12-03T00:00:00.000Z"]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "openDate": "2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "closeDate": "2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "openDates": ["2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "2017-12-03T00:00:00.000Z"]    
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "openDate": "2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "closeDate": "2017-12-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    "openDates": ["2017-12-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "2017-12-03T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "2017-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"]    
  }
```

Then I can run a facet query like this:

```
/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=openDates&rows=0
```

to get the counts I need.

Is there a better way to solve this in Solr?

Ideally, an alternate approach can help bucket by hour or minute, not just days. The above approach will have a very large multi-valued field if we go more granular. Also, is there a good way to fill the holes (i.e. missing dates) with zero counts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DateRangeField](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/DateRangeField.html) will come for the rescue. In schema you will add something like this:

```
<fieldType name="range_date" class="solr.DateRangeField" />
<field name="active" type="range_date" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

You could specify active [range](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html#WorkingwithDates-MoreDateRangeFieldDetails) like this:

```
doc1.addField("active", "[2017-12-01T00:00:00.000Z TO 2017-12-04T00:00:00.000Z]")
```

and later request [range facets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-RangeFaceting) by this field.

Example of params with 1 day granularity (you could change the `gap` param for different values) :

```
      q.add("facet", "true")
      q.add("facet.range", "active")
      q.add("facet.range.start", "NOW/MONTH")
      q.add("facet.range.end", "NOW/MONTH+1MONTH")
      q.add("facet.range.include", "outer")
      q.add("facet.range.gap", "+1DAY")
```

I've added `facet.range.include=outer` to keep exact format response as you like (not including upper and lower bounds). You could change this parameter by [choosing](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html#Faceting-Thefacet.range.includeParameter) something you would like more.

You will get exactly what you need:

```
2017-12-01T00:00:00Z
1
2017-12-02T00:00:00Z
3
2017-12-03T00:00:00Z
3
2017-12-04T00:00:00Z
1
2017-12-05T00:00:00Z
1
```

Full example of the code is [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/scala/RangeDateFacets.scala).